# select() always returns 0

Tags: c++, sockets, select

I seem to have a problem with `select`.

```
while(!sendqueue.empty())
{                                   
  if(!atms_connection.connected)
  {
    //print error message
    goto RECONNECT;
  }

  //select new
  FD_ZERO(&wfds);
  FD_SET(atms_connection.socket, &wfds);

  tv.tv_sec = 1;
  tv.tv_usec = 0;

  retval = select(atms_connection.socket + 1, NULL, &wfds, NULL, &tv);

  if (retval == -1) {
    printf("Select failed\n");                      
    break;
  }                     
  else if (retval) {
    printf("Sent a Message.\n"); 
  }
  else {
    //printf("retval value is %d\n",retval);
    printf("Server buffer is full, try again...\n");                        
    break;
  }
  n = write(atms_connection.socket, sendqueue.front().c_str(), sendqueue.front().length());
}
```

The function belongs to a thread, which, when it acquires the lock cleans a queue using select() and writes to socket in a loop until the queue is empty.

The first time the thread gets the lock it `select()` fine, but the second time it gets the lock and enters the while it always returns 0.

For the record, it used to work fine a while ago, and I haven't changed that code since then.

Comment: Return 0, it is timeout expired

Comment: Your message "server buffer is full" is completely and 100% misleading. It means *nothing happened* within the timeout period, not 'server buffer is full'.

Comment: what does it mean though? any way to handle it? thanks

Comment: If you haven't changed _this_ code, and things stopped working, then it's probably a problem with the code that you _did_ change.

Comment: You should also check what the `select` function does. What you are doing is waiting for up to one second to see if you can write without blocking. It doesn't check that a write succeeded.

Comment: In fact I am wondering why use `select()` at all for sending. Just use `send()` in blocking mode and get rid of the whole headache.

Comment: @EJP yeah the only possible scenario would be when you want to write on one of many descriptors on which some event happened and send should only happen after that event which is monitored through select.

Comment: @EJP I've added the line where i write..although it doesn't get there because of the break

Comment: @user1432779 - Why not use a nickname instead of some digits?

Comment: Btw, `select()` is the worst of all i/o-multiplexing methods, you might at least use `poll()` instead, and if you need highest performance and/or very many sockets you could look at advanced methods like `kqueue` and `/dev/poll` etc.

Answer (score 5):

Selects returns 0 when it has a timeout. The following line specifies a time out to be 1 second.

```
tv.tv_sec = 1;
```

Usually a socket is ready for write and select would return immediately. However, if there is no room in the socket output buffer for the new data, select won't flag this socket as ready for write.

For example, this condition might happen when the other side of the connection is not calling `recv/read`. The amount of unconfirmed data grows and the buffer eventually becomes full. Since the timeout is fairly small, the select returns frequently with return value 0.

Comment: I increased tv_sec to be 5 secs..still didn't work. do you recommend then looping on the select until it's not zero maybe?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to accomplish, but I would check what the other side of the connection is doing (the one that should call `recv`).

Comment: I would simply use a blocking `send` in this case (without `select`). Anyway, do you see that the other end of the connection is receiving anything?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what is mentioned already, select api itself only tells whether a descriptor is ready. It can be used for both reading or writing depending upon what operation is chosen.

In your case, the "message sent" print seems to give the illusion the data is actually written, which is not the case. *You have to make a write call on the descriptor which is returned as ready from select.*

Select does not magically itself reads or writes to a buffer. In case you are a listening server, you call an accept or a read after select call returns successfully. In case you are a client and intend to write (like it appears in your case), you need to make an explicit write() or send() call.

Comment: I added the write(). it was there I just didn't publish it as it wasn't the issue..but thanks :-)